# Why cant I do this in my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

```
def search
  @location = Location.find(params[:location_id])
  start_date = DateTime.strptime(params[:start_date], "%m-%d-%Y")
  end_date = DateTime.strptime(params[:end_date], "%m-%d-%Y")
  @songs = @location.songs.find(:all, :conditions => {:play_date => start_date..end_date}).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 40)
  render 'show'
end
```

Here is my error

```
undefined method `paginate' for #<Array:0x007fb00e49e6c8>
```

all works if i remove the will_paginate but i need it...any ideas or is there a better way to write this controller

Comment: Try searching from Song instead ie: `@songs = Song.find(:all, :conditions => {:location => params[:location_id], :play_date => start_date..end_date}).pageinate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 40)`. The collection returned (a plain old array) from `@location.songs.find()` does not have the pagination methods on it.

Comment: found the solution     @songs = @location.songs.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 40, :conditions => {:play_date => start_date..end_date})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try writing

```
@songs = @location.songs.where(:play_date => start_date..end_date).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 40)
```

The difference? `where` returns an `ActiveRelation` object, while `find` retrieves all the matching objects in an array.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `paginate' for []:Array
```

My will_paninate works perfectly but above error jumped out after upgrading to version 3.0.0.

Add following require will solve the issue:

```
require 'will_paginate/array'
```

Check out this post for the backward compatibility of will_paginate 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

The [will_paginate documentation](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/Troubleshooting) states that combining `.paginate` with `.find` is not the way to go, because `.find` will load everything from your DB before `.paginate` has a chance to restrict the fetch.